# Matlab Special Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there a MATLAB function to generate this matrix?:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... n;
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... n+1;
 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... n+2;
 ...;
 n n+1 n+2     ... 2*n-1];
```

Is there a name for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes indeed there's a name for that matrix.  It's known as the [Hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix).

Use the [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) function in MATLAB:

```
out = hankel(1:n,n:2*n-1);
```

Example with `n=10`:

```
out = 

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11
     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
```

---

Alternatively, you may be inclined to want a [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) based approach.  That is certainly possible:

```
out = bsxfun(@plus, (1:n), (0:n-1).');
```

The reason why I wanted to show you this approach is because in your answer, you used `repmat` to generate the two matrices to add together to create the right result.  You can replace the two `repmat` calls with `bsxfun` as it does the replication under the hood.

The above solution is for older MATLAB versions that did not have implicit broadcasting.  For recent versions of MATLAB, you can simply do the above by:

```
out = (1:n) + (0:n-1).';
```

Comment: Arrived here from a more recent [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71955737/generate-matrix-using-matlab-built-in-function?noredirect=1), for future readers: note that `bsxfun` has now been superseded by implicit expansion, and the alternate offered in this answer is now simply `out = (1:n)+(0:n-1).';`

Comment: @Wolfie I think I'll update this answer to respect the implicit expansion.  This answer was from 2015 after all!

Answer (score 2):

My standard approach is

```
repmat(1:n,n,1)+repmat((1:n)',1,n)-1
```