# Generate matrix using matlab built-in function

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want generate matrix of the form:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

using MATLAB.
I can make code to generate matrix above:

```
for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        idx(i,j)=i+j-1;
    end
end
```

But, I want use MATLAB built-in function to generate matrix above to simplify my code (I don't want using looping again). Anyone know MATLAB built-in function to generate matrix above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB® R2016b and later:

```
[1:3] + [0:2]'
```

Old style:

```
bsxfun(@plus,1:3,[0:2]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[1:3; 2:4; 3:5]
```

This generates a 3 x 3 matrix and simplifies your code down to one line.